# How to show field only if a particular option is selected in Ionic?

Tags: forms, angular, ionic3

I have a form and I want to show this button only if the first option is selected. I am using angular template-driven approach.

```
    <ion-item>
              <ion-label>Address:</ion-label>

              <ion-select ngModel name="estate">
                <ion-option [value]='1'>Estate1</ion-option>
                <ion-option [value]='2'>Estate2</ion-option>
                <ion-option [value]='3'>Estate 3</ion-option>
                 <ion-option [value]="4">Non-Residence</ion-option> 
              </ion-select>

            </ion-item>

            <ion-item *ngIf="estate == 1">
            <button ion-button round color="dark" >Estate1</button>
            </ion-item>
```

Comment: When you select one option from the select element, does the `estate` property get the value of that option? Just ask to know if the issue is there or in the `*ngIf`

Comment: @sebaferreras yes when i do console.log(form) i can see the value has been passed

Comment: What happens if you remove the attr binding in the value, making them just `value="1"` and then in the `*ngIf` you use the `===` operator like this: `*ngIf="estate === 1"` ?

Comment: @sebaferreras i tried it just now removing the attr binding [value] = '1' to value='1'. still no changes also tried both "==" and "===" operators

Comment: Hmm, I think the issue is because `*ngIf="estate == 1"` is looking for a property of your component, but the `estate` is part of the form, and not a standalone property... Let me check how to get the value of it from the form object

Comment: @sebaferreras thx a lot for troubleshooting with me. Pengyy 's answer worked. by adding #estate to the select inputs

Comment: Glad to help, we both learned something today :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should define `estate` by adding `#estate` to `ion-select` element

```
<ion-select #estate ngModel name="estate">
```

and you are binding string `1,2,3,4` to options, so the `ngIf` expression should be `*ngIf="estate.value === '1'"`

refer plunker **[demo(angular)](https://plnkr.co/edit/WUTkUnI5Th8XrZJUeBfe?p=preview)**.